# Ulitização IS DISTINCT FROM - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Qual a melhor utilização desta função no `Postgres` `IS DISTINCT FROM`, fazendo testes obtive o mesmo resultado usando `COALESCE` porem em menos tempo, segue o teste:

````
SELECT COUNT(P.id)

FROM produto P
  INNER JOIN cliente CL ON P.id_cliente = CL.id_cliente

WHERE 
  COALESCE(CL.tp_pessoa,'') <> 'JURIDICA' -- teste com COALESCE, média de 610 ms

  (CL.tp_pessoa <> 'JURIDICA' OR CL.tp_pessoa IS NULL) -- teste com OR, média de 668 ms

  CL.tp_pessoa IS DISTINCT FROM 'JURIDICA' -- teste com IS DISTINCT FROM, média de 667 ms

  OUTRO TESTE:

  COALESCE(CL.tp_pessoa,'') <> COALESCE(P.observacao,'') -- teste com IS DISTINCT FROM, média de 940 ms

  CL.tp_pessoa IS DISTINCT FROM P.observacao -- teste com ```IS DISTINCT FROM```, média de 930 ms, aqui teve uma leve vantagem da função
````

Além do desempenho inferior, é uma função que não é encontrada em outros bancos como o `SQL Server`, mais um motivo para não usá-la.

Fazendo outro teste, onde ambos os critérios podem ser `NULL`, o `IS DISTINCT FROM` teve uma leve vantagem, seria esta sua utilização, onde mais ela se aplica ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparação IS DISTINCT FROM retorna true quando os dados são diferentes, a diferença é que ele trata null como um valor conhecido.

Ele pode ser usado sempre que quiser comparar valores e se deseja ignorar valores null.

Para mais detalhes veja a [documentação do Postgres.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, estou respondendo a pergunta, pois consegui outras informações relevantes sobre o assunto.